# Edit input value before submitting a form without using submit event on the form but somehow on the input

Tags: javascript, html

I have made a JavaScript `input` element which I want to use as a normal HTML `input` inside a form. When the form is submitted I want the input's value to be manipulated by the already written JavaScript code before submitting.

I am aware of using the `submit` event, but it is used on the `form` not the individual elements inside the form. I want something like using `submit` event listener on the input without needing to touch other elements such as `form`.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.

With one exception, no user event that triggers form submission will trigger any event on an `input`.

That exception is if the `input` is the submit button which was clicked / field that triggered submission via the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key.

That said, there's nothing stopping you manipulating the value of an `input` in the form as part of the submit event.

```
form.addEventListener('submit', event => {
    const input = event.target.querySelector("[name='myInput']");
    input.value = `Manipulated: ${input.value}`;
});
```